# Perl: variable undefined using ternary operator

Tags: perl

```
# Does not work; after this line, defined( $x ) == false
# my $x = defined( $$_ ) ? $$_ : "4321" for \$ENV{ASDF}
my $x;
# works fine
$x = defined( $$_ ) ? $$_ : "4321" for \$ENV{ASDF}
```

The idea being: provide a default value for `$x`.

The question is: why must `$x` be pre-declared in this manner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line is equivalent to the following much simpler statement utilizing [`defined or`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Logical-Defined-Or):

```
my $x = $ENV{ASDF} // "4321";
```

As for why someone would jump through so many unneeded hoops?  Can't say.

Comment: The why: hadn't heard of the `//` operator.

Comment: For anyone making use of this answer: this operator didn't exist until perl 5.10.

Comment: Fair enough, tiz one of the reasons we all hang out on SO, to learn new things :).  Btw, the use of a reference was also unneeded.  Could also have done `$x = defined( $_ ) ? $_ : "4321" for $ENV{ASDF}`.  And then `defined` uses `$_` by default, so `$x = defined ? $_ : "4321" for $ENV{ASDF}`

Answer (score 3):

The ending `for` is translated into:

```
for( \$ENV{ASDF} ) {
    my $x = defined( $$_ ) ? $$_ : "4321";
}
```

Thus establishing the lexical scope of `$x`.

Comment: This sucks.  I can't accept both answers, but they both answer my question; one is what I wanted to know, the other is the right way to do it.